# How to identify touchpad for xorg.conf modification?

Tags: touchpad, multi-touch

**UPDATE:** I just upgraded from 17.10 to 18.04.
Couldn't do this earlier as I was in the middle of a large project, and didn't want to take any risk.
The Elan touchpad is now properly reported by xinput.
Now I just have to try to disable the 3-finger tap...

---

I want to change the default behavior of my touchpad.
Too often I accidentally hit the touchpad with 3 fingers (eg when scrolling), which results in pasting whatever happens to be in my clipboard...

I tried some Options in a xorg.d conf, but they had no effect.
My suspicion is that I'm not addressing the touchpad, as I have problems identifying it.

Asus UX310
Ubuntu 17.10

```
$ uname -a
Linux UX310 4.13.0-46-generic #51-Ubuntu SMP Tue Jun 12 12:36:29 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ xinput
⎡ Virtual core pointer                          id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-pointer:13                       id=6    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ xwayland-relative-pointer:13              id=7    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                         id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ xwayland-keyboard:13                      id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]

$ cat /proc/bus/input/devices
I: Bus=0018 Vendor=04f3 Product=3022 Version=0100
N: Name="ELAN1200:00 04F3:3022 Touchpad"
P: Phys=i2c-ELAN1200:00
S: Sysfs=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-6/i2c-ELAN1200:00/0018:04F3:3022.0001/input/input15
U: Uniq=
H: Handlers=mouse0 event14
B: PROP=5
B: EV=b
B: KEY=e520 10000 0 0 0 0
B: ABS=260800000000003

$ dmesg
i2c_hid i2c-ELAN1200:00: i2c-ELAN1200:00 supply vdd not found, using dummy regulator
hid-multitouch 0018:04F3:3022.0001: Ignoring the extra HID_DG_INPUTMODE
input: ELAN1200:00 04F3:3022 Touchpad as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-6/i2c-ELAN1200:00/0018:04F3:3022.0001/input/input15
hid-multitouch 0018:04F3:3022.0001: input,hidraw0: I2C HID v1.00 Mouse [ELAN1200:00 04F3:3022] on i2c-ELAN1200:00

$ udevadm info --query=property --name=/dev/input/event14
  DEVLINKS=/dev/input/by-path/pci-0000:00:15.1-platform-i2c_designware.1-event-mouse
  DEVNAME=/dev/input/event14
  DEVPATH=/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:15.1/i2c_designware.1/i2c-6/i2c-ELAN1200:00/0018:04F3:3022.0001/input/input15/event14
  ID_INPUT=1
  ID_INPUT_HEIGHT_MM=70
  ID_INPUT_TOUCHPAD=1
  ID_INPUT_WIDTH_MM=103
  ID_PATH=pci-0000:00:15.1-platform-i2c_designware.1
  ID_PATH_TAG=pci-0000_00_15_1-platform-i2c_designware_1
  ID_SERIAL=noserial
  LIBINPUT_DEVICE_GROUP=18/4f3/3022:i2c-ELAN1200:00
  MAJOR=13
  MINOR=78
  SUBSYSTEM=input
  USEC_INITIALIZED=3437217
```

When I run `xinput test 6`, activity is shown on the screen when I touch, tap, or click the touchpad.

```
$ xinput --list-props 6
Device 'xwayland-pointer:13':
        Device Enabled (119):   1
        Coordinate Transformation Matrix (121): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000
        Device Accel Profile (244):     0
        Device Accel Constant Deceleration (245):       1.000000
        Device Accel Adaptive Deceleration (246):       1.000000
        Device Accel Velocity Scaling (247):    10.000000
```

I tried to override the touchpad default behavior.

```
$ ls /usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/
10-amdgpu.conf  10-quirks.conf  11-evdev-quirks.conf      40-libinput.conf          70-synaptics.conf
10-evdev.conf   10-radeon.conf  11-evdev-trackpoint.conf  51-synaptics-quirks.conf  70-wacom.conf
```

and created `71-touchpad-disable3touch.conf`.

Example of what I tried:

```
Section "InputClass"
        Identifier "touchpad disable 3finger touch paste"
        MatchIsPointer "true"
        Option "Emulate3Buttons" "false"
        Option "TapButton2" "3"
        Option "ClickFinger2" "3"
        Option "SwapAxes" "true"
EndSection
```

The `SwapAxes` was added to make it very clear if the touchpad configuration was picked up.
Axes were not swapped though, and buttons not remapped:

```
$ xmodmap -pp
There are 10 pointer buttons defined.
    Physical        Button
     Button          Code
        1              1
        2              2
        3              3
        4              4
        5              5
        6              6
        7              7
        8              8
        9              9
       10             10
```

After each edit of the .conf, I restarted my system.

How can I change my touchpad's behavior?

Comment: If you have solved your problem (which is great!), please post the solution as an answer instead of editing the question.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it.

I first upgraded from Ubuntu 17.10 to 18.04.
The Elan touchpad is now properly reported by xinput.

I had still no luck with xorg.conf, so I tried GNOME Tweak Tool

```
$ sudo apt install gnome-tweak-tool
```

Then run the just installed 'Tweaks' app, go to the 'Keyboard & Mouse' section, and set 'Middle Click Paste = Off' and 'Mouse Click Emulation = Fingers'.